# Maven build outside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Initially I didn't have any thing in the default work space of eclipse, so I copied and pasted all the modules and then did the maven build locally by using the command line `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Plocal` .

Now, I have made some changes in the code in Eclipse, and I have done the maven build on the existing code (in the workspace), so I am wondering, since the modules in my workspace are already linked with the eclipse Project Explorer when I did the maven build on the workspace using command line, do I need to run something like "Import Existing Maven" projects on eclipse ? I am just worried, if I do that then it could import another set of folders in the project explorer.Please advise. I am using Eclipse Mars version.

Comment: Your question is not terribly clear, but I don't think doing a Maven build outside of Eclipse will have any impact on the source files.  If you import into Eclipse and the project structure is a bit off, then correct it.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen So basically, once I am done with Maven build outside the eclipse, I can delete the existing workspace, and copy and paste the new maven build stuff in workspace, and then import into eclipse as "Import --> Existing Maven Projects" Is that what you mean?

Comment: I would not approach it this way.  Just import your code as a Maven project and go from there, or create a new Maven project from scratch and then bring in the source code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I Import my code as an Existing Maven project, is eclipse going to overwrite the existing project modules in theproject explorer  or is it going to create separate duplicate modules right below the original one? Just asking as I don't want to mess up my project work space.

Comment: I'm not an expert with Eclipse as I generally work with IntelliJ.  That being said, I think it should be safe to just create a blank Maven project and move in your source code, replacing the POM with the one you already have.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks.One another question. I decided to have anew workspace and then imported stuff using existing maven project. In addition to that do I always need to deploy war file to the existing local tomcat?  I have my local tomcat installed at `C:\Users\<myname>\Documents\<folder>\tomcat`. I have also added the Server in eclipse and specified local path(as mentioned) above.

Comment: I _think_ you should be able to configure Eclipse to deploy the WAR automatically in a location of your choosing.  But I personally always deploy by hand because I prefer it.  You also would probably want to do some cleanup in the `webapps/` folder to remove any stale exploded WARs which might be sitting around.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks. I also prefer to manually do the same. My tomcat is taking 72k ms to start and I do have lot of stale WARs over there , I put them inside old ROOT folder like ROOT_old. Are those WARS responsible for this late start time of eclipse.

Comment: If those old WARs already have exploded folders, then Tomcat should not be doing any additional deployment work on them.  On the other hand, if there are no folders, then yes, Tomcat could be wasting time exploding WARs you don't care about.